# ADF mapping dataflow - how to use byName()

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have this line of code

```
contains(Schema#outputs().properties.conformityRules, regexExtract(toString(byName(#item.column)), #item.value, 0) =='' )
```

It returns error: Column name function 'byName' does not accept column or argument parameters

Is there a way around so I dynamically can reference a column?

**** Update ****
These two objects should be used as filters. If Control column and AlarmSegment exist and both have values the they pass. The column and value are dynamic.

```
 {
                "column": "Control",
                "value": "1"
            },
            {
                "column": "AlarmSegment",
                "value": "PST:A_ALM"
            }
```

Comment: Could you please add the information about which transformation you are using and the sample schema and expected result?

Comment: I am using  a Filter activity. Just updated the filter objects